# How should I understand "tout" in "par les faits tout simples"

Tags: sens, adverbes

This is an excerpt from *Le Horla*:

> Il salua, s'assit et dit: Messieurs, je sais pourquoi on vous a réunis ici
>   et je suis prêt à vous raconter mon histoire, comme m'en a prié mon ami le
>   docteur Marrande. Pendant longtemps il m'a cru fou. Aujourd'hui il doute.
>   Dans quelque temps, vous saurez tous que j'ai l'esprit aussi sain, aussi
>   lucide, aussi clairvoyant que les vôtres, malheureusement pour moi, et pour vous, et pour l'humanité entière.
>   Mais je veux commencer par les faits eux-mêmes, par les faits **tout**
>   simples.

How should I understand "tout" here? Does it modify "simples" or "les faits"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *tout*, placed in front of a name or an adjective, will allow to accentuate the meaning of the word. You could replace it by the word *vraiment*, which means *really*:

> Par les faits **vraiment** simples.
>
> With the **really** simple facts.

In the same idea, take this sentence:

> Il est **tout** petit.

You could translate this sentence has:

> He is **really** little.
>
> He is **so** little.

There, you are accentuating the fact that the person is small.